# Making spatial pie chart using two columns in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib, chart

I am trying to make a pie chart that looks like the one below:

[image]-

I am using GeoPandas for that:

```py
us_states = gpd.read_file("conus_state.shp")
data = gpd.read_file("data_file.shp")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
us_states.plot(color="None", ax=ax)
data.plot(column=["Column1","Column2"], ax=ax, kind="pie", subplots=True)
```

This gives me the following error-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\LSRATH~1.STU\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17992/1047905594.py in <module>
      1 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= (10,10))
      2 us_states.plot(color = "None", ax = ax)
----> 3 diff_env.plot(column = ["WS_MON1","WS_MON2"], ax= ax, kind = "pie")

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    951         if kind in self._pandas_kinds:
    952             # Access pandas plots
--> 953             return PlotAccessor(data)(kind=kind, **kwargs)
    954         else:
    955             # raise error

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    921             if isinstance(data, ABCDataFrame):
    922                 if y is None and kwargs.get("subplots") is False:
--> 923                     raise ValueError(
    924                         f"{kind} requires either y column or 'subplots=True'"
    925                     )

ValueError: pie requires either y column or 'subplots=True'
```

Even after specifying, `subplots=True`, it does not work.

How can I make a pie chart using two columns of the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

In the answer to [How to plot scatter pie chart using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337732/how-to-plot-scatter-pie-chart-using-matplotlib), there is a function to create pie charts and place them by x and y coordinate. You can use it like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/regions.geojson")
df["col1"] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=df.shape[0]) #Create some values to use in the pie chart
df["col2"] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=df.shape[0])
df["x"] = df.geometry.centroid.x #Extract polygons centroid coordinates
df["y"] = df.geometry.centroid.y

# df[["id","col1","col2","x","y"]].head(3)
# Out: 
#    id  col1  col2              x             y
# 0  10     8     6  730688.755515  7.423659e+06
# 1  20     6     9  654384.725161  7.185790e+06
# 2   9     5     0  464723.552684  7.012668e+06


def draw_pie(dist, xpos, ypos, size, ax=None):
    """A function to plot pie charts"""
    """https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337732/how-to-plot-scatter-pie-chart-using-matplotlib"""
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

    # for incremental pie slices
    cumsum = np.cumsum(dist)
    cumsum = cumsum/ cumsum[-1]
    pie = [0] + cumsum.tolist()

    for r1, r2 in zip(pie[:-1], pie[1:]):
        angles = np.linspace(2 * np.pi * r1, 2 * np.pi * r2)
        x = [0] + np.cos(angles).tolist()
        y = [0] + np.sin(angles).tolist()

        xy = np.column_stack([x, y])

        ax.scatter([xpos], [ypos], marker=xy, s=size)

    return ax

ax = df.boundary.plot(figsize=(8,25), color="black", linewidth=1) #Plot the polygon boundaries

for i, subframe in df.groupby("id"): #For each id
    values = subframe.iloc[0] #Extract its values as a series
    slice_sizes = values[["col1","col2"]].to_list() #Extract the values from the values column as a list, like [1, 3]
    x = values.x #The x coord for the pie
    y = values.y #y
    pie_size = 1000
    draw_pie(dist=slice_sizes, xpos=x, ypos=y, size=pie_size, ax=ax)
```

[image]